# C#: Visual studio does not apply indentation rules

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2017. Ever since installing and subsequently unistalling ReSharper, I cannot stop visual studio form indenting my brackets. During removal of ReShaprer, I used an option that essentially said "restore VS details".

What I've tried so far:

- Manually disabling indentation via the Tools menu
- Using the Import and Export Settings Wizard to reset all my settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To automatically indent all of your code

1. In **Tools**, **Options**, select **Text Editor**, **All Languages**, **Tabs**, and then
   select **Smart** from the Indenting group box.
2. To select this option on a per-language basis, select Smart in the
   appropriate folder, starting by selecting Options from the Tools
   menu. For example, to set Smart formatting for Visual Basic, select
   Smart from the Indenting group box in Text Editor, Basic, Tabs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all options (none, block and smart) but it didn't solve the issue. Obviously, I don't want none or block (I want e.g. the variable declarations to be indented in the example above). When I set it to smart however, I again have the problems that the braces are indented in spite of my settings under Formatting.

Comment: You may have an (auto-generated) .editorconfig file in your solution that is over-ruling your Visual Studio settings. If there is, you could try removing it.